# C++ help a warning with pointers

Tags: c++, object, pointers

i need return the name of object, the pointer cabezera pointing to the object, but when run in the console print a warning Segmentation fault.

```
cancion *cola;
cancion *cabezera = new cancion("ca","name","cab","cab","cab","cab","cab",*cola,*cabezera);
cola = new cancion("cola", "cola", "cola", "cola", "cola", "cola", "cola", *cabezera, *cola);


cancion *tmp1 = new cancion ("1","1","1","1","1","1","1",*cabezera, *cola); 
cancion *tmp = new cancion ("1","1","1","1","1","1","1",*cabezera, *cola);
string entrega = "";
tmp1 = cabezera;
entrega = tmp1->getID(); //getID() return a string.
cout<<entrega<<endl;
```

Comment: Please run through debugger to see where the segmentation fault is. Also we need to about the definion of class `cancion`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cancion *cabezera = new cancion("ca","name","cab","cab","cab","cab","cab",*cola,*cabezera);`

Without knowing what the constructor actually looks like, in this case you are trying to dereference cola, which has not been assigned a value, and thus will give you a segmentation fault (technically undefined behavior, but >99% of the time a segmentation fault).